# null == foo versus foo == null

Tags: java, null

This may just be a style question, but I'm reading a Java coding book ('Programming Android') and the writer all declares null first before a variable method, a practice I am not familiar with.  For example:

```
if (null == foo) {
    //code here
}
```

or

```
if (null != foo) {
    //code here
}
```

instead of

```
if (foo == null) {
    //code here
}
```

I can't see how the order would make a difference semantically/syntactically, or am I wrong here?  Really just curious.

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, you mean `==` (equality operator)

Comment: @Reimeus: Exactly what this convention [used to] prevent -- with the "constant" (`null`) on the left, the idea is that you will encounter a compile time error if you forget that second equals sign, as it would be an invalid assignment otherwise.

Comment: In that way writes the code yoda

Comment: e.g. because you avoid aassignment and comparison mistakes. As you have a constant on the peft side and get a compiler warning `"bar" = foo` vs `foo = "bar"` I think it's also called Yoda style

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably a habit left over from C/C++. In C, you would put constants on the left, because if you mistyped `=` instead of `==` there would be an error because you can't assign something to a constant. In Java, this is unnecessary because `if (foo = null)` also gives an error, which says that an object reference isn't a boolean.

Comment: Didn't mean to be harsh on you earlier today. 1+

Answer (score 5):

This is a holdover from C/C++.  It was advantages to put the value on the left of the == operator in case you accidently used the assignment = operator.  The C compiler will catch the  14 = var as an error, but var = 14 will compile, when you meant to type var == 14.  There is not much reason to do this in Java, but some still do it.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes order saves you from null pointer exception e.g. if a `String` variable is coming from somewhere and you compare it like this:

```
if(foo.equals("foo")){
}
```

then you might get **Null pointer exception**. On the other hand if you do it like this:

```
if("foo".equals(foo)){
}
```

then you not only achieve your purpose but you also avoid a null pointer exception in case `String` foo was `null`.

Comment: with Strings it makes total Sense to put the "contstant" first to avoid nullpointers. In any other case, its just a matter of your preferences.
i prefer (object == null)

Answer (score 2):

No difference.

Second one is merely because C/C++ where programmers always did assignment instead of comparing.

E.g.

```
// no compiler complaint at all for C/C++
// while in Java, this is illegal.
if(a = 2) {
}
// this is illegal in C/C++
// and thus become best practice, from C/C++ which is not applicable to Java at all.
if(2 = a) {
}
```

While java compiler will generate compilation error..
There is no really different between two form. There is no performance issue but there are following notes:

1. > First form is readable for code reader, because people usually read
   >   codes Left-To-Right.
2. > Second form is better for code writer, because in java = operator is
   >   for assignment and == operator is for test equivalent, but people
   >   usually using in if statement = instead of ==, by second approch
   >   developer getting Compile-Time-Error because null can't use in
   >   Left-Side of a assignment statement.

**ADDED**

```
if (object = null) {
```

> The convention of putting the constant on the left side of == isn't
>   really useful in Java since Java requires that the expression in an if
>   evaluate to a boolean value, so unless the constant is a boolean,
>   you'd get a compilation error either way you put the arguments. (and
>   if it is a boolean, you shouldn't be using == anyway...)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, and

```
if (foo == null)
    enter code here
```

is the prefered way; however in C, you would put constants to the left since there would be an error if you used `=` instead of `==`